# Scala filter and multiple predicates reporting

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have a 4 predicates

```
  private def pred1(ep:MyClass):Boolean = ep.attr1.contains(true) && func1(ep)
  private def pred2(ep:MyClass):Boolean = ep.attr1.contains(true) && !func1(ep)
  private def pred3(ep:MyClass):Boolean = ep.attr1.contains(false) && func2(ep)
  private def pred4(ep:MyClass):Boolean = ep.attr1.contains(false) && !func2(ep)
```

I then have a list that I want to filter by each of the predicates like so.

```
val ep: Seq[MyClass] = ???

val v1 = es.filter(pred1)
val v2 = es.filter(pred2)
val v3 = es.filter(pred3)
val v4 = es.filter(pred4)
```

How do I get values of `v1, v2, v3, v4` with the correct predicates in a single filter and report it as a `4 tuple (v1,v2,v3,v4)`? Or something similar. I do not want to do this 4 times. I have a huge sequence and this is not optimized

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a fold like this ..

```
  ep.foldLeft[(Seq[MyClass], Seq[MyClass], Seq[MyClass], Seq[MyClass])]
              ((Nil,Nil,Nil,Nil)) { case ((a,b,c,d), i) =>
    (
      if (pred1(i)) a :+ i else a,
      if (pred2(i)) b :+ i else b,
      if (pred3(i)) c :+ i else c,
      if (pred4(i)) d :+ i else d
    )
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks very helpful. I will test it out, I am sure it will work. I was trying to call map and the problem I thought I would run into would be that it would put None or () in my case which I had tried. I think it is not possible to do this with map. Here is what I had tried

val result = es.map {x=>
  val v1 = if(pred1(x)) Some(x) else None
  val v2 = if(pred2(x)) Some(x) else None
  val v3 = if(pred3(x)) Some(x) else None
  val  v4 = if(pred4(x)) Some(x) else None
}